# What is the difference about installing GitLab between 'my server' and 'GitLab server'?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-api, gitlab-api

Recently, I need to management my code to use GitLab, but there is one question

What is the difference about installing GitLab between 'my server' and 'GitLab server'?

I guess for security.....
but, GitLab be able to select unpublished my code to another developer.

So I really wonder about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "GitLab server" you are referring to the repos in [`gitlab.com/explore`](https://gitlab.com/explore), the main difference is that you don't have to install anything: you can create a public or private repo and start pushing there.

If you do install GitLab on your own server, then you can control the access to your own server, but you would need to manage that GitLab instance yourself.

Comment: hmm..what is the 'access control'?...gitlab.com/explore can control access, right?? ....then what is advantage if i install gitlab to my server? thanks for your help

Comment: @dokuemLee You can control the list of users able to login to your server and access your repo you defined as "internal" (meaning access to any logged-in user). As opposed to GitLab.com where any user can access a public repo.

Comment: oh, i got it ! thanks alot :)